# HTTP Interceptor not working with service call

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-httpclient-interceptors

I have created an interceptor to add header, so that I don't have to manually add header to each http request. But the moment I add service call inside my interceptor it wouldn't trigger, I am not sure why. Below is my code.

**Here is my interceptor file**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { GoogleAuthService } from './services/auth/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: GoogleAuthService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('Interceptor: Intercepting request...');
    
    return this.authService.requestToken().pipe(
      switchMap(token => {
        console.log('Interceptor: Token obtained -', token);
        const authRequest = this.addAuthenticationToken(request, token);
        return next.handle(authRequest);
      })
    );
  }

  addAuthenticationToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string) {
    return request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });
  }
}
```

it prints the first `console.log('Interceptor: Intercepting request...');`, but never gets inside the service call to print the second `console.log('Interceptor: Token obtained -', token);`

**Here is my service file**

This function makes  a request to GCP cloud function by passing target URL which returns a token which I want to pass to my interceptor

```
import { Injectable, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, catchError, throwError } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GoogleAuthService {
  audience = 'https://cloud.run.app';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  requestToken(): Observable<any> {
    const requestUrl = "https://us-central1-gcp.cloudfunctions.net/get-token"
    const tokenUrl = `${requestUrl}?url=${this.audience}`
    return this.http.get(tokenUrl)
  }
}
```

This is working fine, if I don't make any service call and hardcode the token as below, the problem shows up when I make service call to get the token

```
import { Injectable, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, from, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { GoogleAuthService } from './services/auth/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  token: string = "5dadbb1d-03fc-11ed-baea-7640edfdd6b4";
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private authService: GoogleAuthService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(this.addAuthenticationToken(request));
  }

  addAuthenticationToken(request: HttpRequest<any>) {
    return request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${this.token}`
      }
    })
  }
}
```

**Here is my module file**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { GoogleAuthService } from './services/auth/auth.service';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './auth.interceptor';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true,
      deps: [GoogleAuthService]
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Here is the browser window screenshot**

[image]

Comment: What error do you have ?

Comment: Surprisingly no error, let me add the screenshot here.

Answer (score 0):

You interceptor should skip the call to the service when it's the service himself that is making the request.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  token: string = "5dadbb1d-03fc-11ed-baea-7640edfdd6b4";
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private authService: GoogleAuthService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if(request.url.includes('get-token') {
      return next.handle(request);
    } 

    return next.handle(this.addAuthenticationToken(request));
  }

  addAuthenticationToken(request: HttpRequest<any>) {
    return request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${this.token}`
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: If I skip the service call, then how do I get the token ?

Comment: Don't skip the service call. The interceptor should skip calling the service when its the service URL that is requested !

Comment: I think this is right, basically, your interceptor was making another http call before going on with the original http call, which makes the interceptor intercept (as one does).  You want your interceptor to not intercept the http call to go get the token otherwise you are just in a loop.

Comment: But I also wonder if you need to call to get a token for every http call?  Why not just get the token once and hold onto it for as long as possible before it expires and just use it in a synchronous context in your interceptor?  Do you need to ask for the token with http on every http call?